# Since moving into a new house we are constantly ill including both my dogs. Is this house the cause?

Tags: moisture, air-quality

We moved into a brand new council house just under 2 years ago in the UK and since then we have had nothing but problems with our health. I am disabled so already had health issues but they have gotten worse. We had gas leaks but when council checked they said it was fine even though I could smell gas so after 3 days of checks I called the emergency gas out who had to condemn my boiler and meter as yes we had 6 major leaks. This house is all plaster board so there are holes in the walls where I have gotten stuck and punctured the walls with my power chair because I do not have enough room to maneuver around. We have constant headaches stomachs pains runny poo the list goes on. Both my dogs are ill 1 is fitting all the time and the other one has constant stomach problems and can't eat. He just lies there shaking and has the runs. The vets are stumped and it's costing me a fortune in bills. We have since found out our house was the one where all the machinery was kept for month's while the built them all so diesel was split everywhere. Our yard where my dogs go floods when it rains so they are constantly walking in it. We are all stressed and I suffer from mental health issues and anxiety which are all been made worse by this. Could our house be making us all more ill or am I just crazy. Please help with advice. Thank you

Thank you for your replies yes we have a carbon monoxide detector it is an electric one which is,wired into the house the same as our fire alarms. Tested it today and that works.
These houses were built on what used to be garages that they knocked down. The council did not put any vents in the houses and the window are very small. I have a wetroom which I cannot use because it floods all downstairs out so for nearly 2 years i haven't been able to run it.  We have has the council out because i vould smell sewerage in the house but all they did was lift the drain flush the toilet and said it's running fine and they couldn't smell anything.  Under our garden is the septic tank for 20 houses. My neighbour washes her yard down and sweeps all the water under the fence and onto out yard
We have wooden floors down not carpet because of my powerchair. 
I swear this house in some way is killing us.

Answer (score 1):

Sick building syndrome is common and comes in many forms. Here’s an article that explains it better:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indoor_air_quality

Also, it could be glue “outgassing”.

Formaldehyde (in glue) out-gasses for several months after it it is made into building materials. Products like particle board in countertops, OSB board in underlayment, etc. are likely items that can out-gas. See here:

https://rarediseases.org/rare-diseases/formaldehyde-poisoning/

You can have your house tested or there are home air tests you can do yourself.

Comment: Lee Where can I buy a home test from please and what is it called?

Comment: @NikkiTired You can Google “air quality home tests” and find several types.  I’d check Amazon or your local Builders  Hardware store.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a carbon monoxide detector? If you do, make sure it works. If not, get one. The symptoms aren't a perfect match, but they are similar, and you have gas appliances.

Comment: Yes we have a carbon monoxide detector and it works